# SFML setFillColor fails to fill color of sf::RectangleShape 2D array

Tags: c++, sfml

For school I got the assignment to make a tic-tac-toe game. I have a grid layout which consists of 9 squares (3 at the top, 3 in the middle and 3 at the bottom), drawn on a background. This way a grid is obtained. But setting the color does not work. In my constructor `GridLayout` I ask for a `sf::Color`, like this:

```
GridLayout(sf::RenderWindow& window, const sf::Color& fillColor, const int& spacing):
// some init
{
    setFillColor(fillColor);
}
```

Also, in my private attributes, I have a grid, which looks like this:

`sf::RectangleShape[3][3] rectangleShapes;`

To set the fill color of all the 9 shapes, I have created the following function:

```
void GridLayout::setFillColor(const sf::Color& fillColor) {
    for (auto& row : rectangleShapes) 
        for (auto& rect : row) 
            rect.setFillColor(fillColor);


}
```

But as shown on the following image, it still appears white, even though `sf::Color::Black` is passed.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to fix it. For some reason, the color resets to white according to the order of how these two functions were called:

```
GridLayout::GridLayout(sf::RenderWindow& window, const sf::Color& fillColor, const int& spacing):
//init
{       
    setFillColor(fillColor);
    createGridLayout();
}
```

Should be:

```
{       
    createGridLayout();
    setFillColor(fillColor);

}
```